# Android 4.4.2 (KitKat): BitmapFactory.decodeStream always returns -1 for the width and height after using inJustDecodeBounds = true

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory, android-4.4-kitkat

When I run the code below on my Nexus 5 (Android 4.4.2), I get -1 for tmpOptions.width and -1 for tmpOptions.height.  On all my earlier android devices and earlier OSes I get a valid positive width and height for my image with this same code.

```
BitmapFactory.Options tmpOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
this.decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(inputStream, false);

tmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, tmpOptions);
```

It seems as though something has changed.  I am using a BufferedInputStream to ensure that I have `marksupported() == true`, in case using `inJustDecodeBounds=true` required a Stream that can be be rewound. Although, that was not needed in earlier versions of Android anyway. I am trying to decode a large image (2540x1080 pixels) but I would expect my latest device with KitKat to support larger images than previous versions of Android.